# How to pass blocks between methods?

Tags: ruby

I have two methods which both except a block, however one of the methods needs to pass its block to the other.

```
def one(&block)
  two(block)
end

def two(&block)
  block.call
end
```

In the real code other parameters are passed and `one` is syntax sugar over `two`.

I want to be able to call both `one` and `two` with a block.

```
one { } # => okay
two { } # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I can see why I get the `ArgumentError`, `two` takes no argument as such. I'm not quite sure how to phrase this but `&block` designates the block appears after the passed in arguments, hence the error.

Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass the `&block` to your second method like so:

```
def one(&block)
  two(&block)
end

def two(&block)
  block.call
end

one { puts "Hello World" }
Hello World
#=> nil
```

**Update**

You could also do something like this

```
def one
  two(&Proc.new)
end

def two(&block)
  block.call
end
```

It will have the same output as above. Do note that if no block is given to one, it will raise an `ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block` so you'd have to check if the block is given by calling `if block_given?`

Comment: Thanks - I used `two(&block)` I didn't realise you could retain the `&` to pass the block as a non-argument argument...

Answer (score 2):

You could do the same with `yield`:

```
def one
  two { yield }
end

def two
  yield
end
```